# How can co-authors check the status of a submitted manuscript in Elsevier Editorial System?

Tags: paper-submission, elsevier

I know that after submitting a paper through Elsevier Editorial System, the corresponding author can check the status of the submitted paper online. But how about co-authors? Can the corresponding author give a permission to the co-authors to enable them to check the status of the paper as well? If yes, how that can be done?

Comment: I guess you can ask the corresponding author for the reference number. Then you just register in the Ensevier webpage and add an accepted article to your webpage. Then you can track its status.

Comment: Ideally, you bug Elsevier to fix their system, and after a few years, you might see some improvement. This makes it better for everyone :-)

Comment: @artalexan The OP is asking about *submitted* papers, not *accepted* ones.

Comment: I found the answer myself  [here](http://help.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/279/p/7923/related/1)

Comment: @Stat: it would be useful if you summarise the answer you found and include the link as an answer to your own question. (Yes, on the SE network answering one's own question is quite allowed.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is No, he/she cannot cannot give any permission to the co-authors after submission to EES and before acceptance, as mentioned [here](http://help.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/279/p/7923/related/1):

> I am a co-author on the paper, I would like to be able to see the
>   status of the manuscript. I have the manuscript number and I am
>   registered on the journal website.
>
> *After submission, you can only see the status of a submitted paper via
>   the corresponding author's EES homepage. You will not be able to
>   search for this submission via your own author's EES homepage.*

So just the corresponding author can check the status before acceptance. But after acceptance, co-author can track the status as well:

> *After acceptance, the article is recorded in our tracking system, you
>   can use the production reference number along with the Corresponding
>   Author's name to track your paper status and add your paper to your
>   personal homepage on http://www.elsevier.com/trackarticle.*

Answer (score 0):

You have received an email just after submission which gives you a link to check the current status of your manuscript. the text of the email is something like this:

"The link below takes you to a webpage where you can sign in to our submission system using your existing Elsevier profile credentials or register to create a new profile. You will then have the opportunity to tailor these updates and view reviewer and editor comments once they become available.

http://www.evise.com/profile/api/navigate/....."

Comment: Is "You" in your answer and link the corresponding author or all co-authors?