# Can co-authors check the status of a submitted manuscript with various publishers?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, authorship

Inspired by the question [How can co-authors check the status of a submitted manuscript in Elsevier Editorial System?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20834/how-can-co-authors-check-the-status-of-a-submitted-manuscript-in-elsevier-editor), I would like to broaden the scope of the question and apply it to various publishers. In general, I feel that by default, coauthors cannot track the progress of a submitted manuscript during the review process.

Are there exceptions to this rule of thumb?

Comment: Some submission systems permit all co-authors to be listed as corresponding authors, which allows all co-authors to check the progress of a submitted manuscript. Moreover, only one corresponding author needs to be publicly listed.

Comment: In relation to @user2768's comment, I would like to mention the distinction between the "submitting" (often a.k.a. "corresponding") and the (long-term) "corresponding" autors via https://doi.org/10.1021/nn301566x

Comment: The editorial states "on submission, one single author must handle submission to and communications with the journal." This might be true for journals considered by the authors, but it certainly isn't true for all submission systems.

Comment: @user2768 I did not want to imply this specific requirement of there being only exactly one submitting author. I mentioned this editorial to introduce different vocabulary for these two roles, in case the discussion here would refer to "corresponding authors".

Answer (score 2):

(probably more suitable as a comment, but I lack the reputation for that)

"Are there exceptions to this rule of thumb?"

At least some publishers that use [Manuscript Central](https://clarivate.com/products/scholarone/) allow this. I am a non-submitting, non-corresponding author on some RSC and ACS papers and can view the basic status of (and download copies of) these manuscripts. It uses email addresses/[ORCID](https://orcid.org/)s to link these to your account, and you may have to have created an account with the relevant publisher prior to submission for this to work.

Comment: A side question: are there public demo systems available for, e.g., Manuscript Central? It would be interesting to see what can be configured (and thus expected) from publisher, and what cannot. E.g., I recently found out that while most instances of MC send out emails to both the primary and secondary email addresses of a user account (+ Cc addresses), one specific instance did not, forcing me to include an extra Cc address that is not requires in others.